# Insufficient privileges - Web service API

Tags: sonarqube

I want to access the web service API to checkout some information of a project regarding especially the code coverage. My request URL I try to use is:

```
https://<host>/api/coverage/show?key=<project-key>
```

The Problem is that I will only get the following response:

```
{
    errors: [
        {
            msg: "Insufficient privileges"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm logged in via valid session in cookie and I have all necessary permissions (i.e. browse permission). So why can't I get data?

Comment: What do you see when you open https://<host>/dashboard/index?id=<project-key> in your browser? If you see the file, you should get the data from the WS. Like for instance on Nemo http://nemo.sonarqube.org/dashboard/index?id=org.codehaus.sonar%3Asonar-plugin-api%3Asrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Forg%2Fsonar%2Fapi%2Fmeasures%2FCoreMetrics.java and http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/coverage/show?key=org.codehaus.sonar%3Asonar-plugin-api%3Asrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Forg%2Fsonar%2Fapi%2Fmeasures%2FCoreMetrics.java

Comment: And thats the thing: I see the dashboard of my project but the API returns "Insufficient privileges"

Comment: Seeing the same issue myself accessing `http://localhost:9000/api/ce/task?id=AVE--W-cg-abcdefghijk` that is output at end of sonar runner scan

Answer (score 0):

As documented [here](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation#api/coverage), this API requires the user to have 'Browse' permission on the project. You will need to pass the credentials using Basic Auth to the server, it should work.

You need to pass `Authorization: Basic <base64encoded-username-password>` in the HTTP header of your request. You can find many tools to generate the code, I use fiddler. In fiddler, go to Tools -> Text Wizard. In the dialog box enter `username:password` (e.g. `admin:admin`) and select 'ToBase64'. Copy this code in the HTTP header and try sending the request again.

Comment: I've tried to compose such a request with fiddler and the corresponding auth header key with base64encoded username and password (so, like have described it). But nothing has changed. I'll retrieve the same response.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that there's a bug in the documentation. The required permission seems to be "See source code" but not "Browse".

Comment: Thanks Simon. Kevin, do you have admin privileges to the server? You can try with those credentials, just to be sure that access permissions are out of the way, and the API is working the way it's supposed to. Also, which version of Sonar are you on?

Comment: I don't believe that it is a problem with the user privileges. Because also as admin we get the same error. Maybe some additional things in the sonar configuration is missing?
We're using SonarQube 4.5.1 (LTS).

By the way: I've also "See source code" permission.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (SonarQube 4.5) and turned out that the issue was in the name of the project, that is, the value for the first part of the *key* parameter (before the colon).

It happens that the name to use is not the name it appears in the dashboard.

To find out the real name of the value:

1. Browse in SonarQube to the file you want to get coverage
2. Hover over the  title of the project at the top left corner. The link that appears should be something like this:

   http://server/dashboard/index/project-name

Use that "project-name" even if it has already a colon in it.

```
http://server/api/coverage/show?key=server-name:path-to-file
```

Where "path-to-file" is something like src/main/java/myFile.java

Finally don't forget the authentication part.
Using curl:

```
curl -u user:password http://server/api/coverage/show?key=server-name:path-to-file
```

Definitely the error message returned by SonarQube is totally misleading.